# Import data from a .json file to a Brain.js neural network

Tags: javascript, json, neural-network

I want to import data from a data.json file into the neural network (which uses the Brain.js framework).Here is the part which is supposed to bring that data to the network and analyse it:

```
const result = brain.likely(
  require('data.js')
,net);

alert("This is the result: " + result);
```

And get that data analysed by the neural network and shown to the user.
Here are the contents of the data.json file for reference:

```
{
  'Rating1': 0.12434213,
  'Rating2': 0.987653236,
  'Rating3': 0.432543654
}
```

For your information this is on written on node.js enviroment.

Comment: Which environment are you working in? Browser or Node? Also, is data.json something you want uploaded by a user, or is it in the same directory as your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data.json file is in the same directory:

```
fetch('data.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        const result = brain.likely(json, net);
    });
```

Alternatively, with async/await:

```
(async () => {
    const json = await (await fetch('data.json')).json();
    const result = brain.likely(json, net);
})();
```

If done through a file upload:

```
// target input element
const input = document.querySelector('input');

// upload event
input.addEventListener('change', () => {
    const file = this.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('load', e => {
        const json = JSON.parse(e.target.result);
        const result = brain.likely(json, net);
    });
    reader.readAsText(file);
});
```

If done through Node:

```
const json = require('./data.json');
brain.likely(json, net);
```

Useful resources for handling files:

- [Using files from web apps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications) - practical examples on how to use the FileReader API
- [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) - how to use files already on your server in the browser
- [Node's File System readFileSync method](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) - to read file contents synchronously in a Node environment
- [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) - native JS method to convert a string to JSON, useful in all environments